# Service URLs no longer working - appear to have changed

Tags: url, service, google-apps-script

Spreadsheet based Apps that were published as services had URLs of this form:
https: //spreadsheets3.google.com/a/macros/my-domain.com/exec?service=AKfycbwly1SYZhdnPOoKfkH_xB7oMKDeYifYm8M

Today, these URLs are resulting in an error page with a Google Drive logo and the message "Google Docs has encountered a server error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please contact us.". They have an HTTP 500 error if you look at the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google appear to have changed their URL scheme for published scripts. I couldn't find any advice or release notes re this. They are now of the form: https: //docs.google.com/a/macros/my-domain.com/s/AKfycbzvopSddGc3E4KL_nLmxR2fgOXLxNvmliBgXkiJ/exec

To get the new URL, go into your script > Publish as Service... and copy it from the URL box.

Comment: Maybe I've only been writing scripts for about 6 months, but the "new" URLs your referencing are what I've been publishing under for 6 months.

Comment: Yes, these "old" URLs had been happily in production since 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I've raised this in the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1399

Please provide the requested information there (the full URL), either in the issue tracker to directly to me via email if you don't want to share it publicly.