# Inserting published apps script from a spreadsheet to page has stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I have been publishing scripts from spreadsheets, grabbing the url, pasting it into the insert apps script gadget dialog, and changing the "docs" to "sites" for a while now and has been very successful except for today. Did something change between GAS, Google Spreadsheet, and Google Sites that stopped this process recently?

Update 6/18/12

In response to comment:

Based on Peter's comment, the url change did affect the process. But the change is not specific to the issue posted here. All of the discussion has urls based on "sites" only, and does not discuss published urls from spreadsheets that contain "docs" which does not work with the Apps Script Gadget. The process posted in the question is not a stable process which in turn could not be reliable if there was a change. So a new "workaround" may need to be found in order to use Apps Scripts from spreadsheets as a service on Google Sites.

Really Published Spreadsheet Script Urls should work with Google Sites just as the Google Sites Scripts Urls do.

Comment: Yes I think there was a change. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991455/service-urls-no-longer-working-appear-to-have-changed/10991456#10991456 - perhaps it will help you.

Comment: @EricKoleda: "This URL is not recognized as a valid Apps Script"

Comment: The related issue status is  `FIXED`.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to a recent change in the URL format. Please star this [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1415) for updates.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw the interface for the GAS change also. Something is definitely in the works.